# Set 'HiddenFor' value to the selected dropdown list value

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, html.hiddenfor

I have the following dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOrderCodeId, new SelectList(Model.OrderCodesList, "OrderCodeId", "DisplayString"))
```

Now the `OrderCodesList`has the following: `OrderCodeId`,`DisplayString` & `Percentage`

How can I set a `HiddenFor` value to the `Percentage` of the value selected from that dropdownlist? (Below code has to be complete according to pseudo cause I'm not sure what to do next - if it is even possible).

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FinancialSupportPercentage, new { @Value = Model.OrderCodesList.Where
```

pseudo:

```
OrderCodesList.Select 'Percentage' 
 Where
    'OrderCodeId'
 is the `Selected 'OrderCodeId` from the `DropDownListFor`
```

Comment: You can use jquery and Ajax. For the onchange event in dropdown, get the id and get the percentage for that id.

Comment: A `DropDownListFor()` method only generates options with a `value` attribute (and the display text). If you want the value of an additional property, you would need to use ajax to call a server method and get it based on the selected value. But that would be a bit pointess - you may as well just get it in the POST method when you submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way:

**Class**

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderCodeId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayString { get; set; }
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetPercentage(int OrderCodeId)
{
    var data = _dbContext.List
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.OrderCodeId == OrderCodeId)
        .Percentage;

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOrderCodeId, new SelectList(Model.OrderCodesList, "OrderCodeId", "DisplayString"))
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FinancialSupportPercentage)

<scripts>
    $('#SelectedOrderCodeId').on('change', function () {
        var selectedIndex = $(this).val();

         $.ajax({
             url: '/ControllerName/GetPercentage',
             data: { OrderCodeId: selectedIndex },
             method: 'GET',
             success: function (result) {
                 $('FinancialSupportPercentage').val(result);
             }
        });
    });
</scripts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may want something on client-side JavaScript.  The server-side code I think you want is:

```
@{
  var entity =  Model.OrderCodesList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.OrderCodeId == Model.SelectedOrderCodeId);
  double percentage = 0;

  if (entity != null { percentage = entity.Percentage }
} 

@Html.Hidden("FinancialSupportPercentage", percentage)
```

I used hidden as it gives you direct access to the value; HiddenFor usually extracts the value from the model.

The above approach works well if you were doing everything on the server, and if that is the case, then this will work fine.  But if the user changes the dropdown, do you want the hidden to change?  If you do, you need javascript.

Comment: I'm getting Unexpected number on 'double percentage;'

Comment: What exactly is 'percentage'? For me it is Model.FinancialSupportPercentage